# Count the number of occurences of a comma separated string

Tags: mysql, count

I am needing a way to count comma separated values like this - any
suggestions please?

Table:

```
id (int) | site (varchar)
1        | 1,2,3
2        | 2,3
3        | 1,3
```

Desired output:

```
site | # of occurrences
1    | 2
2    | 2
3    | 3
```

Comment: 1. Don't start with a comma-separated string.

Comment: or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into exactly what you're doing, I'll assume you have a `sites` table.  If so, it's technically achievable with something like

```
SELECT sites.site_id AS site, COUNT(1) AS `# of occurrences`
FROM sites
INNER JOIN table ON FIND_IN_SET(sites.site_id, table.site)
GROUP BY sites.site_id
```

Performance of that will be appalling, as there is no way to use an index, and the data will be able to get inconsistent very easily.

What the comments in your question are alluding to, is to use a relational table of some description, where instead of storing a comma-separated list, you store a row for each 'occurrence'